# Grunt not found error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: heroku, gruntjs

I'm getting the error below:

```
remote:        sh: 1: grunt: not found
```

when I'm deploying my code to Heroku server.

My install scripts in package.json is like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "grunt heroku:production && bower install",
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
```

I set heroku config like

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Also I made

```
export BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/mbuchetics/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-grunt.git
```

but nothing has changed. I have grunt and grunt-cli in both dependencies and devDependencies.

So where am I wrong?

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a fix?